# convert from long timestamp to datetime

Tags: python-2.7, timestamp

```
    from datetime import datetime as dt
    stTime = timesTampValue
    stDate = dt.fromtimestamp(stTime)

##ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform localtime()/gmtime() function
```

This code works when timesTampValue is 1574431447609, but in some cases timestamp ends with L like 1574431447609L

I tried with converting it to string, then replace L and again convert it to float/int, it didn't work.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by

```
stDate = dt.fromtimestamp((stTime *1.0)/1000)
```

https://currentmillis.com/